# How can I execute a Vim selection or range in bash without replacing it?

Tags: vim

I'd like to select some text in vim and then execute it in bash. I know of the following procedure:

1. select text using `V` or `v`
2. `:!!`

However, this replaces the selection with the output of the command. What if I don't want that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Type the `:w` command like this:

```
:w !command
```

As you type it, it will appear like this:

```
:'<,'>w !command
```

See

```
:help :w_c
```

Comment: This is correct, but take care not to do `:w! command` by mistake.  If command is a program you have write access to, it'll overwrite the program, and you won't be able to undo the change since that wasn't the buffer that was open.

Answer (score 8):

In **vim 8.0**, you can select a range of lines and run `:terminal bash`. This will open a terminal running `bash` with your selection as stdin.

`:terminal node`, `:terminal ruby`, `:terminal python` seem to work nicely as well.

Comment: In  8.2: `E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version`. Maybe one needs to build with special flags.

Answer (score 0):

Every 6-8 months I need this, forget how, and end up here. Here is the answer I'll want in the future:

**To run the visually selected text from vim in an escaped shell via register:**

- Copy selection to the register "a by typing `"ay`.
- Open vim command mode with `!<CTRL-r>a`

(Skip named register `"a` and just use the default `0` if you're feeling lazy)

---

**Visual instructions:**

[image: Vim visual selected text]

type `"ay`

[image: command mode, <CTRL-r>a]

[image: vim shell escape running bash command]