# How do I execute a Vim selection or range in bash without replacing it?

Tags: bash, vim

I have the same question in this post.

[How can I execute a Vim selection or range in bash without replacing it?](https://superuser.com/questions/330343/how-can-i-execute-a-vim-selection-or-range-in-bash-without-replacing-it)

But the accepted answer in this post, didn't work for me. The command isn't picking up the selected text in vim.

What am I missing?

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!

Answer (score 4):

You can use this command to pipe the lines in the current visual selection to a `bash` shell:

```
:'<,'>w !bash
```

The shell will read the script from its standard input, which is the pipe getting the lines from Vim.

Note that this will use the whole lines around the visual selection, so if it doesn't start on the first character or ends on the last character, those will still be sent as part of the run of the external command.

(The other answer was correct in most part correct, except that it didn't mention piping *to a shell* in order to have it executed. I'm also somewhat puzzled about the mention of `:!!` there.)

If you want to run a small, short command, typically something that fits a single line, you can also do this:

1. Yank it. If it's visually selected, just type `y`. If it's the current line, in normal mode use `yy`.
2. Type [`:!`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3A%21cmd) to start running an external command.
3. Type [`Ctrl-R "`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-R), to insert the contents of the default register in the command line.
4. Finally, press enter to execute the command.

Comment: I want to run the highlighted command. It is a part of the current line. For example: `command to run is: ls -l file`

when I am selecting `ls -l file` and trying to run `'<,'>w !bash`, it is taking the entire line and not just the selected text.

Comment: @Rishabh See the last part of the response. Yank it with `y`, then start a `:!` and retrieve the command with `Ctrl-R` followed by `"`.

Comment: @fibraden that's cumbersome and un-vimly. Thanks for quick response though.

Comment: @Rishabh Well, you can always create a mapping...